# Quasi-rigid bodies in relativity and decomposition of energy

Tags: special-relativity, energy, rigid-body-dynamics

In relativity there can be no perfect rigid solids, the [Born rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rigidity#Definition) is as close as you can get and yet it is severely constrained (Herglotz-Noether theorem). For that reason, rigid solid mechanics does not have an interesting relativistic extension.

Yet, if we consider a solid in stationary rotation from a system in which its center of mass-energy is at rest, intuitively it seems reasonable to believe that we could express its energy as a function $E(\Omega)$ of the antisymmetric tensor $\Omega$ giving the angular velocity:

$$\Omega = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y\\ 
0 & \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x\\ 0 & -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then applying a Lorentz transformation, we would have the energy $E(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{\Omega})$ for an arbitrary system, but this form would be indivisible between translational and rotational kinetic energy, as in classical mechanics. My question is whether for this restricted case we could generalize the classical equation:

$$\boldsymbol{L} = \frac{\partial E_{rot}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\omega}}$$

where now we consider an antisymmetric tensor $\mathbf{\hat{L}}$ instead of a vector, for representing the angular momentum, i.e., $\mathbf{\hat{L}} = F(\boldsymbol{\Omega})$

---

**My attempt**: For a body deformed in a sphere in stationary rotation around Z-axis with $\omega_z = \omega$:

$$E_{rot} = \int \frac{c^2 \text{d}m}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} = \iiint_V \frac{\rho c^2}{\sqrt{1-(\omega r \sin\theta)^2/c^2}}r^2\sin\theta\ \text{d}r\text{d}\theta\text{d}\phi $$

$$E_{rot} = 2\pi\frac{c^3}{\omega} \,\int _{0}^{R}\!\left[ \ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt {{\frac {{\omega}^{2}r^2}{c^2}}}}{1-\sqrt {{\frac {{\omega}^{2}r^2}{c^2}}}} \right)  \right]\rho r\text{d}r = \frac{2\pi c^3}{\omega}\rho\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(R^2-\frac{c^2}{\omega^2} \right)\ln \left( \cfrac{c+\omega R}{c-\omega R} \right)+\frac{Rc}{\omega}\right]$$

due to the deformations that Herglotz-Noether theorem predicts, there would be until the body is put in stationary rotation, the density will almost certainly not be uniform. Ignoring this effect, we considered $\rho = \text{constant.}$ (a good aproximation for low values of $\omega$) to evaluate the the integral explicitly.